# plist number type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

when you create a plist and choose number for the type for one of the entries, what type of object is returned when you call on that information later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the type of object that will get returned to you.

Comment: If you choose string then is it going to be just an NSString as well?